# Google colab : can't open file 'xml_to_csv.py': [Errno 107] Transport endpoint is not connected

Tags: python, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook, object-detection-api, tensorflow2.0

I'm trying to open the file 'xml_to_csv.py' using this code

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/gdrive')
!sys.path.append("/content/gdrive/My Drive/TFConfig/TFmodels/research/object_detection/")
!python xml_to_csv.py
```

I keep getting this response:

```
Drive already mounted at /content/gdrive; to attempt to forcibly remount, call drive.mount("/content/gdrive", force_remount=True).
/bin/bash: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `"/content/gdrive/My Drive/TFConfig/TFmodels/research/object_detection/"'
/bin/bash: -c: line 0: `sys.path.append("/content/gdrive/My Drive/TFConfig/TFmodels/research/object_detection/")'
python3: can't open file 'xml_to_csv.py': [Errno 107] Transport endpoint is not connected
```

What could be the cause of the error? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `sys.path.append` is a python function. Executing it in the default shell (`/bin/bash`) does not makes a lot of sense. Next, if you want to add something to the variable `$PATH` of your system, you should not use `sys.path.append`. This function modifies the `$PYTHONPATH` variable, which is used to define the default search path for module files. (In case you would want to import some code with `import`, the python interpreter will look in all the folders contained in the `PYTHONPATH`. Read more about `PYTHONPATH` in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH).

---

That clarified, to execute your python code using the default interpreter, the simplest way is to use an absolute path :

```
!python "/content/gdrive/My Drive/TFConfig/TFmodels/research/object_detection/xml_to_csv.py"
```